# Flutter-Getx Different hasCodes for the same Controller (Getx is also a big problem.)

Tags: flutter, dart, get, flutter-getx

When you first log into the program, everything works fine. I have Products in the app. These products can be added to the cart.

1. I log in to my account.
2. I add a product to the cart.
3. I go to the basket
4. The product is there.
5. I log out of my account "Get.offAllNamed('/');"
6. I enter Username and Password to login again.
7. home page pops up products appear.
8. I enter the detail page of the product.
9. I add the product to the basket.

   10. I go to the basket

There are no products in the cart. I want to add a product to the cart again. But the product does not fall into the basket.

I tested something like this to find this problem.

first I looked at the "hasCode" of the Controller I created when entering the application. Then after logging out, I looked at the "hasCode" of the Immediately Controller again. What I see is that these codes are different.

The Cart I see the second time I log in is for the new hasCode. The added basket falls to the Controller connected to the old hasCode.

Comment: It's impossible for us what's wrong without seeing the code, but it's also kind of hard to show the entire project here. My only guess is that you create different controllers at different places and you refer to the wrong one at certain spots